# Need finishing tips for 50 yr old semi rough sawn wood paneling in a living room

Tags: finishing

Looking for finishing tips for old semi rough sawn boards in a living room.
The wood is very dry and not very attractive as it sits now and I do not want to polyurethane it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a bit too broad for here. Why don't you want to use polyurethane? It's one of the best finishes going, and one of the most versatile.

Comment: I was not looking for a glossy type of finish, more of something to show the wood without a shine

Comment: Well even gloss varnishes when thinned heavily penetrate well and don't give a decent gloss until multiple coats have been applied. But regardless of that, they make matt versions of most varnishes and waterbased finishes if you want a fully matt final surface. Matt waterbased poly might be a great option for you here.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a mantle out of an old barn beam.  I used a wire wheel first, then sanded with 80 -> 120 -> 220 sandpaper using a random orbital.  Wiped with mineral spirits and then two coats of tung oil, lightly sanding again with 220 between coats.  It has a nice matte finish and tung oil doesn't build a film like poly does.

Sorry for the blurriness, it's a screenshot from a video I took.
[image: https://imgur.com/a/fwwXSYZ]